# Injecting Maven project information into Swing Application Framework resources?

Tags: java, swing, maven-2, appframework

I have a Maven project using the Swing Application Framework and would like to inject project information from the pom.xml into my application's global resources to avoid duplication.

The base application (provided via netbeans) uses Application.title, Application.version, Application.vendor, Application.description resources etc for Window titles and about box configuration but I can't find a way to set these values programatically at run time and I'm not a maven maven so don't have the skills to inject them at build time.

Anyone have any recommendations on how best to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 4):

You could try using [filtered resources](http://www.sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-description.html).  If you create a property file, say `src/main/resources/com/myapp/app.properties` that looks like this:

```
version=${project.version}
name=${project.name}
id=${project.artifactId}
```

Them you need to enable filtering in your `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>src/main/resources</resource>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resources>
</build>
```

Now when maven builds your project, it'll expand the property file, and place it on the classpath.  Then you can just call [getResourceAsStream("/com/myapp/app.properties")](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) to read it into your app.

Whist maven does automatically create a file `/META-INF/maven/$groupId/$artifactId/pom.properties`, this may not have all the information you need.

Comment: Works! The ´src/main/resources´ just has to be wrapped by a directory tag and the filtering tag must sit in the resource tag as well.

Comment: the 'filtered resources' link does not work or is behind a paywall... use this instead: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Answer (score 1):

You can keep those in separte property file and read it from both pom.xml and your application.

Another option is to read pom.xml file from classpath (mvn will put it in META-INF folder) and parse it from there as plain xml file.

I would go with first option.

Comment: Neither of these options address getting the information into the resources as expected by the Swing Application Framework though.

Comment: Or are you suggesting that I reference the SAF properties to populate the maven pom?  How would I go about that?

Comment: @Rob That's how I understood it. Have one property file with application name etc. and let Maven and Spring load it.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using the maven-antrun-plugin. Pass the necessary maven properties to ant and create an ant build script which modifies an application properties file or the spring context configuration directly.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to generate a separate properties file with the properties-maven-plugin and then add this properties file to the application bundle names:

For the `pom.xml` to write `application.properties` file:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>write-project-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <outputFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties</outputFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
    ...
</build>
```

For including the `application.properties` into your application:

```
public class MyApplication extends SingleFrameApplication

    public MyApplication() {
        super();
        addGeneratedApplicationProperties();
    }

    private void addGeneratedApplicationProperties() {
        ResourceManager resourceManager = getContext().getResourceManager();
        getContext().setApplicationClass(MyApplication.class);
        List<String> bundleNames = new LinkedList<String>(resourceManager.getApplicationBundleNames());
        bundleNames.add(0, "application");
        resourceManager.setApplicationBundleNames(bundleNames);
    }

    ...
}
```

However, I find the maven-filter-solution way more elegant.